# The resulting value of a simple jQuery function wont display in my 'answer' span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Circles!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="math.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>The area of a circle given the circumfrence</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="group">      
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <label>Circumfrence</label>
            <button type="button" id="button">Calculate</button>
       </div>
       <div id="answerbox"><span id="answer"></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my js:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#button").click(function() {
            var input = $("#input").val;
            var answer = (((input * input) * Math.PI) * 0.25);
            $(answer).append("#answer")
            $("#answerbox").fadeIn(700);
        });
    });
```

So the 'answer' value wont display in my 'answer' span, which is inside my 'answerbox' div. What is wrong here?

Comment: `$("#answer").append(answer);`

Comment: or `answer.appendTo("#answer");`

Answer (score 2):

You must use correct the val and append in code:

Correct:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#button").click(function() {
                var input = $("#input").val(); // changed added '()'
                var answer = (((input * input) * Math.PI) * 0.25);
                $("#answer").append(answer); // changed exchaned answer #answer
                $("#answerbox").fadeIn(700);
            });
 });
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the code in reverse order:

```
$(answer).append("#answer") // wrong
$('#answer').append(answer) // right!
```

Plus you made a mistake calling `.val`, it needs the parenthesis since that is a function:

```
var input = $("#input").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Part One, val

val is a function

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1

Your current code is assigning the function to the variable input.

To call the function and retrieve the content of the input field, you need to call the function using parentheses.

```
var input = $("#input").val();
```

### Part Two, append

append takes the content to add as a parameter.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

You must first use the CSS selector syntax to choose where to append the content, then pass the content.

```
$("#answer").append(answer);
```